# How do I position my rows label to the left side in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, alignment, row

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
}
```

So here I'm displaying the rows.

Notice how on this image, the label is positioned towards the right side and there is a big gap from the left side?

[image: Rows Label]

How do I place it closer towards the arrow? I don't want the user to have to resize to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `RowHeaderStyle`, in `dataGridView1` properties, then follow the pictures below

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it's giving me a `NullReferenceException`. I put this in the Form1.Designer.cs code.

Comment: put it in the behindcode,not in the Designer.cs ,put it in the constructor

Comment: I put it in the constructor but it's still giving me the same thing. Also, what do I changed "therequiredcell" to?

Comment: you can give the column index value,0 or 1 or 2...but not in quotes

Comment: I tried `this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;`, zero being the header I believe but it'st still giving me the same result in the image. :( Did you try that code maybe? If you did do you mind showing me a pic of your result?

Comment: @puretppc hey wait i am going to post the image on how to do it..!!

Comment: Thanks so much it worked :) http://i.imgur.com/gEnhYX8.png Image used the same width as if I asked this question (41)